# Linux Centos with dmesg timestamp

Tags: linux, centos, dmesg

I would like to read my Centos 5.x dmesg with timestamp, how do I do this?

Comment: later dmesg support the -T flag, maybe try using -T if your dmesg supports it.

Comment: centos 7+ supports `dmesg -T`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dmesg` reads the Kernel log ring buffer.  It doesn't do timestamps.  What you should do is configure syslog to grab the kernel logs from that buffer and send them to a file (if it isn't already set to do so).  Note, default CentOS 5.x syslog config sends kernel logs to `/var/log/messages`, as I recall.

If you'd like to send all kernel (dmesg) logs to `/var/log/kern.log`, using the default syslog daemon, you'd add a line like the following to `/etc/syslog.conf`

```
kern.*                         /var/log/kern.log
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For anyone looking that's running CentOS 6, I found it in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

Comment: Yep, with CentOS (and RHEL) 6.x, they changed the default syslog daemon from the old sysklogd to rsyslog.  It's available as a (supported) package for RHEL/CentOS 5.x, too.

Comment: Well, I've had this on my list of things to figure out, but now you've saved me some googling

Answer (score 9):

There is solution "Enabling Timestamps for dmesg/Kernel Ring Buffer"

You could add:

```
printk.time=1
```

to kernel cmdline.

As for me, I have added to rc.local on all machines with puppet. It's easier for me) :

```
if test -f /sys/module/printk/parameters/time; then
   echo 1 > /sys/module/printk/parameters/time
fi
```

Comment: that works for me

Comment: Using `rc.local` is really kind of an ugly solution for this (using `rc.local` is almost always an ugly solution to anything).  A better solution would be to put `printk.time = 1` into `/etc/sysctl.conf` or a file in `/etc/sysctl.d/`.  That's the reason these files exist.  Cramming stuff into `rc.local` will eventually leave you with a fragile, convoluted, messy, unreliable start-up.

Comment: This what is in comment from @ChristopherCashell is the only correct answer to this question. It's a shame it's not actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've written this simple script. Yes, it's slow. If you want something faster you either actually write a script on perl, python or something else. I'm sure this simple script can give you the hang of how it can be calculated.

Please note I ignored the seconds fraction registered in each line (after the . in the timestamp).

```
#!/bin/bash
localtime() {
 perl -e "print(localtime($1).\"\n\");";
}

upnow="$(cut -f1 -d"." /proc/uptime)"
upmmt="$(( $(date +%s) - ${upnow} ))"

dmesg | while read line; do
 timestamp="$(echo "${line}" | sed "s/^\[ *\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g")"
 timestamp=$(( ${timestamp} + ${upmmt} ))
 echo "${line}" | sed "s/^[^]]\+]\(.*\)/$(localtime "${timestamp}") -\1/g"
done
```

I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

A little perl script as below. It's a general way, and I'm not the author.

```
dmesg|perl -ne 'BEGIN{$a= time()- qx!cat /proc/uptime!};s/(\d+)\.\d+/localtime($1 + $a)/e; print $_;'
```

- `perl -n` is a way to read standard input and read into variable $_.
- The body (not the BEGIN section) is then run once for each line.
- BEGIN runs the code in {} once.
- $a is the start of dmesg since the epoch
- The s/... command takes the value in $_ and substitutes the #####.###### part of the timestamp with the "localtime" version of the dmesg offset ( $1) added to the system start time ($a)
- print $a prints the dmesg with the locale friendly time stamp substituted for the "seconds since boot" time stamp.

Comment: This answer needs some more explanation.

Comment: @kasperd Here is what it means:

- perl -n is a way to read standard input and read into variable $_. The body (not the BEGIN section) is then run once for each line.
- BEGIN runs the code in {} once.  $a is the start of dmesg since the epoch
- The `s/...` command takes the value in $_ and substitutes the #####.###### part of the timestamp  with the "localtime" version of the dmesg offset ( $1) added to the system start time ($a).
- `print $a` prints the dmesg with the locale friendly time stamp substituted for the "seconds since boot" time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Script modification in case line do not begin with a "["

```
#!/bin/bash
localtime() {
 perl -e "print(localtime($1).\"\n\");";
}

upnow=$(cut -f1 -d"." /proc/uptime)
upmmt=$(( $(date +%s) - ${upnow} ))

dmesg \
| while read LINE; do
    if [ "$(echo ${LINE} | egrep -v "^\[")" == "" ] ; then
        timestamp=$(echo "${LINE}" | sed "s/^\[ *\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g")
        timestamp=$(( ${timestamp} + ${upmmt} ))
        echo "${LINE}" | sed "s/^[^]]\+]\(.*\)/$(localtime "${timestamp}") -\1/g"
    else
        echo "${LINE}"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an update on Plutoid's suggestion, removing the leading spaces from the timestamp.

```
dmesg|perl -ne 'BEGIN{$a= time()- qx!cat /proc/uptime!};s/( *)(\d+)\.\d+/localtime($2 + $a)/e; print $_;'
```

- perl -n is a way to read standard input and read into variable $_.
- The body (not the BEGIN section) is then run once for each line.
- BEGIN runs the code in {} once.
- $a is the start of dmesg since the epoch (seconds)
- The s/... command takes the value in $_ and substitutes the \s*#####.###### part of the timestamp with the "localtime" version of the dmesg offset ( $1) added to the system start time ($a)
- print $a prints the dmesg with the locale friendly time stamp substituted for the "seconds since boot" time stamp.

Comment: And like the original answer, it needs some explanation. Can you edit your post, break it down, and step through it?